# How to read 6 RC remote channels using Attachinterupt for every channel

Tags: arduino-uno, pwm, remote-control

How can i use the attach interupt command and read rc channels in background. I am in doubt that attach interupt is only applied to 2 pins just and cant be used to get data from other pins.

Comment: Please spell out what you mean by "rc channel"; eg add a link to a specification for rc channels.  Note, the Uno has plenty of pin-change-interrupt pins, which can be used (eg) for software-serial i/o [with one software-serial channel active at once, in typical software-serial implementation]

Comment: I mean external interupts,(radio control channels).

Comment: You can use `PCINT`s. The only downside is that they all share one single interrupt routine (ISR).

Comment: Bilal, please edit the question and spell out what you mean by "radio control channel".  Is it an input? An output? Are you talking about controlling RC servos?  Edit the question and add a link to an actual specification.

Comment: I already tell you what you should investigate in your other question on the same topic. If you'd read the entire answer there you would know the answer to this question already.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking but you can have as many interrupt sources on a single interrupt pin as you want.  When the interrupt happens in your ISR (Interrupt Service Routine) you simply check each one and process the ones that are valid.  Be sure to do one final check before exiting as another could happen while servicing the first one.

Gil